# Karma can not load browser launcher

Tags: angular, firefox, plugins, karma-runner

```
 [launcher]: Cannot load browser "FireFox": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

I've followed all the steps ( that I know of ) :

```
npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev
```

`karma.conf.js`

```
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
  require('karma-ie-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
```

`\node_modules\karma-firefox-launcher\` is present as expected

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {

    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
```

NOTE : I have no problem with launching IE browser

Could this be a misleading error where the real problem is that Karma can't find Firefox.exe ?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add into the `browsers` property the name of the browser you want to launch, in this case "Firefox":

```
browsers: [/*'Chrome'*/, 'FirefoxDeveloper', 'Firefox'],
```